# Protractor e2e testing suggestions about code complexity

Tags: selenium, protractor

I know my question will get marked as to broad but I didn't think of another place to ask it.I work in QA and  month ago i started learning protractor by myself so i can test our projects with protractor there was no one to guide me i learned all by myself and google so I wanted you guys to check the code i made and give me some suggestions. Does it look like it should,because i think its worthless it gets the job done but i feel it is still beginner level, and there is none to guide me so i know the level i am at the moment any suggestions are welcome.My config file pretty basic.

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine2',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['page.js'],



   onPrepare: function() {

    var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');

}
}
```

My specification file:

```
/*
##############################################

FUNCTIONS in helper_functons:

getsite();

logIn();

mainPageItem();                 | 0 - Recipes | 1 - Collections | 2 - Profiles |

openRecipe(index);

createRecipe (name,description,step,numStep,ingName,numIngr,addToCollections,share);

deleteRecipe(recipeName);  //must use getMainPageAndRefresh()

openRecipe(index);

browseRecipe();

openCollection(index);

createCollection(name,description);

openUser(index);

getNotifications();

goToProfile();

browseProfile();

getMainPageAndRefresh();

goToTimeline();

openLegal(index);

useSearch(textString);

createPost(postName);

logOut();

##############################################
*/




var functions = require('./helper_functions.js');

var uName = 'asd';

var pass = 'asd';


describe('Hooray',function(){





    it('Gets site',function(){

        functions.getSite();

    });


    it('Logs in ',function(){

        functions.logIn(uName,pass);

    });


    it('Recipe options',function(){




        browser.sleep(9000);



    });



    it('Logs out',function(){


          functions.getMainPageAndRefresh();
          functions.logOut();

    });


});
```

And I am using another file where i created helper functions so my tests look more readable this is where the main code is http://pastebin.com/KgXCh74m I uploaded on pastebin because it is 500 lines. My idea was to call a function whenever you need it and test it in the page.js file.

Comment: I would suggest you post this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. It's intended for code review questions like this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for code review. You might be able to get help at [codereview.se], but you will need to be more specific than asking for "some suggestions."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at your code, it seems you have put all your elements in a function and accessing them in your specs. In general this way of accessing elements would lead to some **Flaky** tests and you would not be able to run test scripts confidently and error free.

Protractor's community widely encourages the usage of **Page Objects**. Protractor has some good documentation,they have specifically mentioned style guide http://www.protractortest.org/#/style-guide to get started.

Some of the tips from my experience while writing protractor tests:

- Avoid `browser.sleep` for page loads , instead use `browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10000);`
- Use `Expected Conditions` for interacting with web elements `elementToBeClickable`, `elementToBeSelected` etc.
- Use Page Objects efficiently. Avoid accessing/performing actions on elements in page objects. It has to be done inside the specs i.e.

your `page.js` should look like this -

```
  var somePage = function() {
  this.username = element(by.id('someId')); //Here we are only defining the elements
  this.password = element(by.id('someId'));
  this.button = element(by.css('someCss'));
  this.login = function(uid,pwd) { // If we are using functions in page objects, we would just access the defined elements above rather than defining them in the function (reusability & decoupling).
  this.username.sendKeys(uid);
  this.password.sendKeys(pwd);
  this.button.click();
  };

 };
```

In the above page object if the `username` or `password` element changes you only have to change them, no need to touch the `login` function.

your `spec.js` should look like this -

```
 var SomePage = require('path to your page.js');

 describe('page', function() {
 var page = new SomePage();

 it('should test page', function() {
 page.username.sendKeys('username'); // Here we are performing the action on the elements.
 page.password.sendKeys('password');
 page.login(username,password);

 });
 });
```

- Maintaining test data in a separate JSON file.
- Set `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true` while dealing with non-angular pages
- Use `CssSelectors` as much as you can to identify elements.
- Since Protractor is community driven --> Follow protractor on GitHub, StackOverflow & Gitter.

You would get all the updates/issues from these platforms so that you can solve your issues or ask for help, these awesome folks would help you!

Comment: Your answer is very concise and  clear will help me alot just having trouble with the Use Page Objects blindly. I kinda can't understand what you mean by: Avoid accessing/performing actions on elements in page objects. It has to be done inside the specs. Would you mind to elaborate?

Comment: Updated my answer to provide more insight, please check if it helps!

Comment: It is crystal clear now thank you :)